# Requests limit per hour

Tags: request, frequency

How to limit requests per hour from one IP like it is in Twitter? For example, I want to provide 100 requests per hour. Is there any solution? Apache modules? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start simple.

- Use the concept of API keys(Lets say
  its a [guid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) mapped to a domain or an
  account).
- Every time your API is hit take that
  key and increment its corresponding counter.
- Write rules to limit based on your
  counter(in this case hours)
- Reset.

Blocking by IP is not advisable.[NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) being the problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it by IP. People from a whole university, company or internet cafe may share the same IP. It's best if you inject a cookie with random value to the first http response for each client in order to identify uniqueness.

Comment: @Sam152: the uniqueness by cookie? Definitely. Do you know any other means of ensuring user uniqueness?

Comment: I don't want to enter limits for all users and all pages but only for specific API pages (xml, json and so on). I mean, only bots will access such pages. I guess it's too difficult for human to read plain XML or JSON. ;-) 

Thanks for answer!

Comment: IP limiting is the most reliable way to identify users, and blacklist them if need be.  However, you should implement "whitelisting" as Twitter does, so that universities etc. that share an IP can still have access with reasonable limits.

Comment: @pop850 How do you propose one gets their hands on a list of mass shared IPs, especially with ISPs sometimes changing IPs around?